# Get full path of current zsh startup file (e.g. zshrc or zshenv)

Tags: zsh

Is there a way to get the full path of the current zsh startup file being processed (e.g. zshrc or zshenv)? In other words, imagine I have a zshrc file that can either be located at `/usr/local/etc/zshrc` or `$HOME/.zshrc`. Inside this zshrc file, I need to do different things depending on its location. The usual `$0` doesn't work, because it contains the path to the zsh binary instead of the zshrc script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With prompt expansion, `%N` gives you that (the current script/sourced-file/function).

So you can do:

```
print -P %N
```

or get it from `${(%):-%N}`.

See also the `$funcsourcetrace` for the files of the call stack.